# Would it be accurate to say that the economies of most of the countries are capitalistic?

Tags: macroeconomics, statistics, capitalism

What is the proportion of countries that are capitalistic? What is the proportion of the planet's population who live in such countries? How is this, (somewhat subjective?)

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to check this is by looking at the [economic freedom index](https://www.heritage.org/index/ranking) 
As we can see, this is a scale, there is no perfect capitalistic country and most of the countries are not very free economically